# Can not save a record in SQL Server database with linq to entities

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

```
PROGRAMMINGEFDB1_DataEntities context = new PROGRAMMINGEFDB1_DataEntities();
//context has two tables Contact & Address (the linq model)

var contact1 = Contact.CreateContact
  (1000, "Camey", "Combs", DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now);          
context.Contacts.AddObject(contact1);
context.SaveChanges();
```

I am utterly frustrated because after much study I can not update a simple table
in my SQL Server 2008.

This means C# is so complicated that a task that should be simple is so obscure to me?

Shall I try another language that really without hesitation updates the SQL Server table?

Comment: what is the error message that you are getting?

Comment: If nuclear plant software updated reactors state without hesitation we would have had now a dozen of Chernobyls and Fukushimas. Maybe you could tell what is really happening when you call SaveChanges. What is the exception's message? Or it simply does not add any data?

Comment: You know maybe it's because of your primary key .i had the same problem before and my problem was PK .but i don't remember how i solved that,just show our table in your question .